# Windows 10 constantly prompts for permission to use precise location

Tags: geolocation, uwp, windows-runtime, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have a very simple application that uses realtime location data to obtain relevant information, developed in C# as a UWP 10.0 application.

My interaction with the geolocation API is very simple: I only checked `Location` in the "Package Manifest" under "Capabilities" and I only use the following API call:

```
var locator = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
var location = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
```

When this call is first made, Windows 10 throws up an "Allow this application to use your precise location [yes | no]" dialog. Selecting "yes" seems to "save" this choice for around 5 minutes or so; subsequent attempts at obtaining the user's position within the next five minutes go through (I believe they return the cached value, as it never seems to change), but more than 5 minutes later, the permission dialog is always shown once more (even though the user has already authorized it).

From my reading of the geolocation API documentation on MSDN, I can find nothing to suggest that this is the intended behavior. Under privacy settings in the metro control panel, this application is under the list of apps allowed to use the precise location. What's more, other apps in that list with precise location enabled have never prompted me to allow them access to the precise location past the first time.

What am I doing wrong here and how can I prevent this dialog from constantly popping up?

EDIT

With `await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync()`, the permissions are cached so long as the exe is not modified/re-compiled.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replicate your problem. But according to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation), it clearly mentions, that you need to call `RequestAccessAsync()` before any calls.

So when I made change from your lines of codes, to below, permission Request window showed up only once and subsequent calls were made directly.

```
GeolocationAccessStatus accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
if (accessStatus == GeolocationAccessStatus.Allowed)
{
    Geolocator locator = new Geolocator();
    Geoposition location = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
    locText.Text = location.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude + Environment.NewLine + location.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting very random results with this, even though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator#Windows_Devices_Geolocation_Geolocator_RequestAccessAsync says this method only prompts for permission once. It randomly lets through requests and blocks w/ a permissions dialog on other calls to `RequestAccessAsync()`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `RequestAccessAsync()` is implicitly called; the documentation says that geolocation data will be blocked if that method is not called, and I had no such issues.

Comment: Oh, I figured out what is happening: if the app is modified, a dialog is shown. That's not the documented behavior, though.

Comment: @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi What do you mean by app modified?

Comment: if the binary has changed.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I i am not wrong, when the App Binary is changed, that is considered a new app. So you need to provide permission again since it is a new app.

Comment: Yes, but I'm pretty sure there's a way to keep your app identity across versions (probably involves signing) because the other apps in my permissions list do not exhibit this behavior.